# Laravel query where clause on the last record of the associated table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am developing a Laravel application. I am having a problem with querying associated two tables using a where clause. This is my database schema.

```
patients
========
id, name, email, password, created_at

treatments
==========
id, created_at, disease, note, patient_id

treatment_logs
=============
id, status, created_at, treatment_id
```

My database schema is very simple. Now what I would like to do is I like to create a query that fetch the treatments of user with the last treatment_logs status is 1. This is my query

```
class Patient extends Model {

    public function intensiveTreatments()
    {
        return $this->treatments()->whereHas('treatment_logs', function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->take(1)
                ->where('status', 1);
        });
    }

}
```

The issue with that query is that does not matter what the last record status of the treatment logs is. As long as there is a treatment_logs with a status of 1, it is going to return the records. But I only want to fetch the records with the last treatment_logs that has the status of 1. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JOIN:

```php
public function intensiveTreatments()
{
    return $this->treatments()
        ->select('treatments.*')
        ->join('treatment_logs', 'treatments.id', 'treatment_logs.treatment_id')
        ->where('treatment_logs.status', 1)
        ->where('treatment_logs.id', function($query) {
            $query->select('id')
                ->from('treatment_logs')
                ->whereColumn('treatment_id', 'treatments.id')
                ->orderByDesc('id')
                ->limit(1);
        });
}
```

Or integrate it into `whereHas()`:

```php
public function intensiveTreatments()
{
    return $this->treatments()->whereHas('treatment_logs', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 1)
            ->where('id', function ($query) {
                $query->select('id')
                    ->from('treatment_logs as latest')
                    ->whereColumn('latest.treatment_id', 'treatment_logs.treatment_id')
                    ->orderByDesc('id')
                    ->limit(1);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonas. But it there a way to get it using my current approach as well, please?

Comment: I added a solution for `whereHas()`. It's the same the approach, only a bit slower.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jonas.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `->with('treatment_logs', function($query) { [... same clauses you use in whereHas...] })`. This happens, because your query is filtering treatments not treatment logs. So, when you, for example, do this:

```
$patient = Patient::with('intensiveTreatments')->get();
```

You are actually eager loading only the treatments, and not treatment logs. Which is why, when you later access the treatment logs of each treatment, they are unfiltered.

Let me know if I need to explain better - my terminology here is not perfect.